# Converting Php code to C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, php, sql, database, visual-studio

I have a somewhat okay knowledge in Php but I recently started Visual Studio and I was wondering how would I go about converting my code to Visual Studio. I wanted to create a combo box that will print out the main category then the sub category under it then the items under it and so on until all main categories are finished.

I had no idea how to write them on C# so I first created the code in PHP and tried to dissect them and so far my current code in Visual Studio is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        sc.Open();

        //For Main Category
        SqlCommand get_maincategory_name = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM maincategory", sc);
        SqlDataReader dr2 = get_maincategory_name.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr2.Read())
        {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2["maincategory_name"].ToString());

            //For Sub Category
            SqlCommand get_subcategory_name = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE maincategory_id='1'", sc);
            SqlDataReader dr3 = get_subcategory_name.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr3.Read())
            {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("--" + dr3["subcategory_name"].ToString());

                //For Inventory
                SqlCommand get_inventory_name = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE subcategory_id='1'", sc);
                SqlDataReader dr4 = get_inventory_name.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr4.Read())
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add("----" + dr4["item_name"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        sc.Close();
    }
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
echo "<select>";

// FOR MAIN CATEGORY
$maincategory_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM maincategory") or mysqli_error();
while($got = mysqli_fetch_assoc($maincategory_query))
{
$maincategory_id = $got['maincategory_id'];
$maincategory_name = $got['maincategory_name'];
echo "<option disabled>$maincategory_name</option>";

    // FOR SUB CATEGORY
        $subcategory_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE maincategory_id='$maincategory_id'") or mysqli_error();
        while($got = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subcategory_query))
        {
        $subcategory_id = $got['subcategory_id'];
        $subcategory_name = $got['subcategory_name'];
        echo "<option disabled>--$subcategory_name</option>";

            // FOR ITEM
            $item_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE subcategory_id='$subcategory_id'") or mysqli_error();
            while($got = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_query))
            {
            $item_id = $got['item_id'];
            $item_name = $got['item_name'];
            echo "<option>----$item_name</option>"; 
            }
        }
}

echo "</select>";
```

The problems I'm having:

1. It's only showing the first main category name and nothing else.
2. I'm currently figuring out how to put `dr2["maincategory_id"]` (to replace the 1) inside the sql statement under WHERE but I'm having trouble figuring out what's the syntax on how it wouldn't be interpreted as a string.
3. I don't know how to disable(or to make read-only) certain parts of the combo box.

Comment: Is this winforms, or webforms? (im guessing its one of the forms, because of the method name, but you should clarify)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it's for Windows Forms.

Comment: 1. When you step through in the debugger, where does it fail?  2. You need to use query parameters for that.  (Which you *should* be doing in your PHP code as well.)  3. If you build a `ComboBoxItem` object and add that to `comboBox1.Items` instead of just a string then you can set additional options on that `ComboBoxItem` object before adding it.

Comment: 1. When I click the combo box, there's only 1 value inside which is the first maincategory_name in my maincategory table.

2. Yeah I'm currently in a website looking at various ways to enter it to the sql. Oh and yeah, I should've used the .''. one for my php but let it got since it was for testing purposes.

3. Seems fair, I mean that's the reason I could refined my php's combo box easily since I created it in the first place. Forgot about that, Thanks

Comment: I've made some progress although I don't know what I did was correct, I closed then opened the cs just below the //For Sub Category comment and now it displays all of the sub category from the first main category BUT it still doesn't seem to display the items under its sub categories but I'll try fiddling around this as this might somewhat, lead to an answer.